# Oracle ADF LOV based query and return the result set

Tags: oracle-adf, lov

I am new to Oracle ADF. My situation, There are two LOVs. First one has 2 values, emp and dept. Second LOV gives the values based on the first one. I have did this using LOV Switcher. Now I need to show the result row, based on the both the selection. For ex: Selecting emp and next selecting xyz person name. I need to show all details of that person. Similarly selecting dept and next selecting abc dept name, then need to show all the details of that dept.

My Approach:
Considered two tables, and in the managed bean applied the view Criteria to the selected table (chosen from the first LOV) and filter the table based on the second value, got the result row and enabled that table using (emp/dept)Table.setVisible(true). This method worked for this scenario. If I have more values in the first LOV, How should I solve this. Can you please share any better approach for these kind of scenarios.
For more tables this method wont be effective

Answer (score 0):

I can only give a general answer here as you did not provide your exact JDev version.
Take a look at af:dynamicComponent (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E50629_01/adf/TROAF/tagdoc/af_dynamicComponent.html) and watch this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TwIKt7e4vEw that show how to use this.
The better you describe your use case the better we can help you.